# PHP: How to sort XML alphabetically by attribute before "for each" loop

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

### The setup:

I have an external XML file I have no control over, here is it:

#### 001.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Gallery xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ID="001" Name="001">
<Images>
<ImageGalleryEntry Name="1 John" Description="Doe" FileName="830358.1john.png" Width="100" Height="100">
<S3Key>accounts/b2d174c1-a408-4d58-9d48-1490ac4e9f9b/site-37857/cms-assets/images/830358.logooraclehealthsciencesthumb.png</S3Key>
<S3ThumbnailKey>accounts/b2d174c1-a408-4d58-9d48-1490ac4e9f9b/site-37857/cms-assets/thumbnails/830358.logooraclehealthsciencesthumb.png</S3ThumbnailKey>
<ContentLength>1309</ContentLength>
</ImageGalleryEntry>
<ImageGalleryEntry Name="11 Jane" Description="Doet" FileName="943702.11jane.png" Width="100" Height="100">
<S3Key>accounts/b2d174c1-a408-4d58-9d48-1490ac4e9f9b/site-37857/cms-assets/images/943702.logorochethumb.png</S3Key>
<S3ThumbnailKey>accounts/b2d174c1-a408-4d58-9d48-1490ac4e9f9b/site-37857/cms-assets/thumbnails/943702.logorochethumb.png</S3ThumbnailKey>
<ContentLength>1403</ContentLength>
</ImageGalleryEntry>
<ImageGalleryEntry Name="10 Jack" Description="Smith" FileName="965501.10jack.png" Width="100" Height="100">
<S3Key>accounts/b2d174c1-a408-4d58-9d48-1490ac4e9f9b/site-37857/cms-assets/images/965501.pwclogo.png</S3Key>
<S3ThumbnailKey>accounts/b2d174c1-a408-4d58-9d48-1490ac4e9f9b/site-37857/cms-assets/thumbnails/965501.pwclogo.png</S3ThumbnailKey>
<ContentLength>7021</ContentLength>
</ImageGalleryEntry>
</Images>
</Gallery>
```

I also have a php code that takes this info and puts it out in html nicely:

#### index.php fragment

```
<?php
$url = '001.XML';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach($xml->Images->ImageGalleryEntry as $item) {
    echo $item['FileName'] . "<br/>" . $item['Name'] . "<br/>" . $item['Description'] . "<br/><br/>";
};
?>
```

#### The output is:

> > 830358.1john.png
> >     1 John
> >     Doe
> >     
> >     943702.11jane.png
> >     11 Jane
> >     Doet
> >     
> >     965501.10jack.png
> >     10 Jack
> >     Smith

The problem is that I actually need it ordered by the Name attribute, like this:

> > 830358.1john.png
> >     1 John
> >     Doe
> >     
> >     965501.10jack.png
> >     10 Jack
> >     Smith
> >     
> >     943702.11jane.png
> >     11 Jane
> >     Doet

Note that the XML constantly changes, so the php should automatically order them alphabetically by Name. I'm guessing I need to somehow sort alphabetically all the ImageGalleryEntry tags by their Name attribute before entering the for each loop, but no clue how to do that.

Please provide an actual way to do it, I'm new to php, and won't know what to do if you say something like "make an array".

Comment: Beware never write answers when your tired, I was going to sleep then realized my answer had been fundamentaly flawed so rebooted my laptop to come and delete it. Sorry I didn't take the fact they were objects into account when suggesting the sort function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). This should work:

```
<?php
$url = '001.XML';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$items = array();
foreach($xml->Images->ImageGalleryEntry as $item) {
    $items[] = $item;
};

// Custom sort on the names of the items:
usort ($items, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['Name'], $b['Name']);
});

foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item['FileName'] . "<br/>" . $item['Name'] . "<br/>" . $item['Description'] . "<br/><br/>";
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer, simple, and using the same basic principle. You rock!

Comment: For some reason when I used this, the $items became an array of simplexml objects and then, usort never worked. I figured I had to change from $a['Name'] to $a->Name and do the same on the foreach after and then it worked.